# How many kingdoms are there actually?

Tags: taxonomy, classification

I am wanting to learn (memorise) some of the tree of life; the classification of organisms. So I have come across a lot of kingdoms in my research. Basically, I don’t want to waste my time learning the wrong thing, so my question is this. Is there an official or most recent system of classification, some authority in organism classification that we look to? After kingdoms it seems pretty clear, the phyla in (say Animalia) seem pretty defined and uncontraversial.

These are all of the ‘kingdoms’ I have found while researching. Some are called kingdoms in one source and not another. I know that some overlap others. This is just to throw every possible example out there.

Animalia, Apusozoa, Archae, Archaebacteria, Archezoa, Bacteria, Biliphyta, Chromista, Chromophyta, Ciliofungi, Cryptophyta, Eufungi, Euglenozoa, Excavata, Filastera, Fungi, Monera, Nucleariida, Plantae, Proteoarchaeota, Protista, Protozoa, Rhizaria, True bacteria, Viridiplantae

I don’t ask that you go through them and explain them. Only what the actual system of classificating organisms is. On that note. As far as I’m aware, there’s two types of domain systems. Two are Eukaryota, Archae/-bacteria, Bacteria. Another is Eukaryota, prokaryota. A clarification on this too would be appreciated.

Comment: All of the hierarchical classification schemes are somewhat arbitrary. There is a real tree (with some complicated attachments due to horizontal gene transfer), but the labels placed on different levels of the tree are made up and subject to opinion and argument. The kingdoms are probably the most poorly defined within that classification because as a group they are not monophyletic at all.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! As @BryanKrause says, there is no "correct" answer since these are classifications made assuming a simple branching topology that can not completely encompass the complexity associated with living organisms. The [wikipedia article on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_(biology)) and the many linked articles are a good place to start learning about this subject. ——— As for domains, "prokaryota" is invalid since it is **not** monophyletic.

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Comment: Why do you wish to memorize this? Science involves understanding, not recall of “facts”.

Comment: @David as you can see I am not a biologist. I lurk more in the realm of mathematics, and so naturally, systems of organisation interest me, so why not that system which organises all living organisms. It's mostly for trivia because I think it's interesting; I don't intend to use these 'facts' in my occupation when I'm older.