# Are bacteria members of Kingdom Monera or a separate domain by themselves?

Tags: taxonomy

The openstax biology textbook by Rice University says: "For example, after the common beginning of all life, scientists divide organisms into three large categories called domains: Bacteria, Archaea, and Eukarya."

But the latest edition of the Indian biology textbook (grade 11) speaks of a Five Kingdom Classification: Monera, Protista, Fungi, Plantae, and Animalia. It also says: "Bacteria are the sole members of the Kingdom Monera."

Which of these is correct? Are bacteria members of Kingdom Monera or a separate domain by themselves?

Answer (score 2):

A domain is a higher level of organization than a kingdom, so they do not necessarily conflict. Please see [this lecture](https://www.etsu.edu/uschool/faculty/tadlockd/documents/bio_chpt18sec3show.pdf) for more context. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-domain_system) also describes this at some length. There are additionally [other questions on this site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90463/how-many-kingdoms-are-there-actually?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C20.5911) that discuss the issue, though none directly seem to answer your question.

The domains were introduced instead of the 5-kingdom model due to molecular work establishing the very very large differences between bacteria, archaea, and all other forms of life to be more representative of the actual biological relationships, and particularly the large molecular differences between the otherwise very similar-seeming archaea and bacteria.

The 5 kingdom are an older, more qualitative and less precise grouping. There are now [other models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_(biology)) that have a larger number of kingdoms under the domains (which are sometimes called other names like superkingdoms). These kingdom models nest more or less naturally under the domain model.

Of course, all taxonomies are somewhat arbitrary. The domain model is an attempt to make the groupings resemble evolutionary history more, and outward organismal characteristics less.

Comment: So, which kingdoms are currently under the domain Eukarya?

Comment: @Thomas Did you bother to follow any of the links in Maximilian's answer?